# best media type to return a Flux as soon it is available through Server Sent Events to Angular/RxJs/observer

Tags: angular, spring, rxjs, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

Context: a Spring Web Flux returning a Flux to Angular in a Server Sent Event style.

Personal Knowledge:

According to [other stackoverflow topic](http://%20https:stackoverflow.coma546875214148175)

Media type applicationjson will buffer the Flux in memory and
 serialize it in one pass.

Media type applicationstream+json will flush on the network each element of the Flux
 input. This behavior is handy when the stream is infinite, or when you want
 to push information to the client as soon as it's available.

Based on before two premisses I choose by applicationstream+json because I want "to push information to the client as soon as it's available" instead of "buffer the Flux in memory and
 serialize it in one pass".

Well, if I add MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON as produces in my WebFlux endpoints bellow it is fine when reading from Spring webclient but it doesn't work with Angular/RxJs connecting via SSE

```
// Delay 0.5 second
@GetMapping(path = "/search-with-delay/{parte_da_palavra}")
public Flux<Sugestao> getSugestoesDelay(@PathVariable("parte_da_palavra") String parte_da_palavra) {
    return sugestaoService.findAllMySugestoes("name", parte_da_palavra).delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(500));
}

@GetMapping(path = "/search/{parte_da_palavra}")
public Flux<Sugestao> getSugestoes(@PathVariable("parte_da_palavra") String parte_da_palavra) {
    return sugestaoService.findAllMySugestoes("name", parte_da_palavra);
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

//SERVICES
import { SseService } from './sse.service';
import { NosseService } from './nosse.service';

//MODELS
import { Sugestao } from './sugestao';

//RXJS
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  sugestoes$: Observable<any>;
  restItems: any;

  //### SSE
  searchSseWithDelay(searchValue: string): void {
    this.sugestoes$ = this.sseService
      .getServerSentEvent("http://localhost:8080/sugestao/search-with-delay/" + searchValue);
  }

  searchSseWithoutDelay(searchValue: string): void {
    this.sugestoes$ = this.sseService
      .getServerSentEvent("http://localhost:8080/sugestao/search/" + searchValue);
  }

  //### Without SSE
  searchWithDelay(searchValue: string): void {
    this.sugestoes$ = this.nosseService.getWithoutServerSentEvent("http://localhost:8080/sugestao/search-with-delay/" + searchValue);
  }

  searchWthoutDelay(searchValue: string): void {
    this.sugestoes$ = this.nosseService.getWithoutServerSentEvent("http://localhost:8080/sugestao/search/" + searchValue);
  }

  constructor(
    private sseService: SseService, private nosseService: NosseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


}
```

And its services

Without SSE

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Sugestao } from './sugestao';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class NosseService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getWithoutServerSentEvent(url: string): Observable<any> {

        return this.http
            .get<Sugestao[]>(url)
            .pipe()
            ;
    }
}
```

With SSE

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Sugestao } from './sugestao';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SseService {
  sugestoes: Sugestao[] = [];
  constructor(private _zone: NgZone) { }

  getServerSentEvent(url: string): Observable<any> {
    this.sugestoes = [];
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      const eventSource = this.getEventSource(url);
      eventSource.onmessage = event => {
        this._zone.run(() => {
          let json = JSON.parse(event.data);
          this.sugestoes.push(new Sugestao(json['id'], json['name'], json['phone'], json['account']));
          observer.next(this.sugestoes);
        });
      };
      eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        if (eventSource.readyState === 0) {
          console.log('The stream has been closed by the server.');
          eventSource.close();
          observer.complete();
        } else {
          observer.error('EventSource error: ' + error);
        }
      }

    });
  }
  private getEventSource(url: string): EventSource {
    return new EventSource(url);
  }


}
```

Googling around I found basically saying [I MUST USE text/event-stream](https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2017/11/04/full-reactive-stack-with-spring-webflux-and-angularjs/)

"If we request content without using an Accept header, or setting it to application/json, 
we'll get a synchronous, JSON-formatted response.
If we want to use the Server-Sent Events support in Spring to implement our full reactive stack,
 we set in our request (explicitly or behind the scenes) the Accept header to text/event-stream, 
 therefore activating the reactive functionality in Spring".

And finally reading about HTML5 I found in [Mozila document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource)

"An EventSource instance opens a persistent connection to an HTTP server, 
which sends events in text/event-stream format. 
The connection remains open until closed by calling EventSource.close()."

Well, after that I really got confused. I will for sure use Angular/RxJs/SSE, I mean, I will not use Spring WebClient on my client side at all. As far as I can see, MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON is the best choice in my business requirement but it seems because I am using SSE I must prefer MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM and when try to use any MediaType returning Events Stream the way I am used to code observers aren't correct.

So my straight question is: what is the most appropriate MediaType to set in my endpoint which is intend to return Flux soon the data is available to Angular/RxJs/Oberver using HTML 5 Server Sent Event feature?

Comment: You've already answered your question, you should use `MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM` for SSE. All it does is add `data:` to the start of each json chunk, which is a specification of SSE. The only reason to use `MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON` is for communication between applications. Looks like `application/stream+json` might be getting scrapped in the future anyway https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21283

Answer (score 0):

Spring developers state:

> The "application/stream+json" is deprecated in favor of "application/x-ndjson". The latter is now also supported out of the box in the Jackson Encoder and Decoder. While it is not an officially registered media type, at least it's a common convention that seems to be in use while JSON lines doesn't even have that. There is also JSON Text Sequences and that is possible to use still with newline as the separator but "application/json-seq" would need to be registered with the Jackson Encoder and Decoder. As for separators other than newline, I'm not sure that Jackson's non-blocking parser supports that.

In summary, use line-delimited JSON with "application/x-ndjson" supported as a media type out of the box and used as a replacement for "application/stream+json". Alternatively, register any other mime type and as long as it's a line-delimited JSON format it'll work the same. The mime type itself is just a convention for describing the format and as long as both sides understand it, it's enough.